# Complex SQL query with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am working on a CSV file and I need to get values with a specific query. It is simple with SQL but I am unable to do it with LINQ. For instance how do I write the following query with LINQ:

```
SELECT outer_table.SONG_COUNT, COUNT( outer_table.CLIENT_ID ) AS CLIENT_COUNT
   FROM (SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (
   my_table.SONG_ID
   )) AS SONG_COUNT, my_table.CLIENT_ID
   FROM data AS my_table
   GROUP BY my_table.CLIENT_ID
   ) AS outer_table WHERE outer_table.SONG_COUNT=346
   GROUP BY outer_table.SONG_COUNT
```

Comment: Use `LinqPad` https://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Thanks @AfnanAhmad

Do you have any idea for this case?

Comment: or Linker: http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: @Nuh Koca what you have tried so far ? Better to download LinqPad and its easy to convert sql query to linq in LinqPad. You need to come with a specific case. It would be hard to understand for any one what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Someone will need to explain to me why it's a good idea to convert sql to linq so linq can generate your sql. Use [QueryFirst](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst) (disclaimer: which I wrote). Your SQL is directly executable in your c# app. Plus numerous other advantages.